# Increasing door knob bore size

Tags: doors

My door has a 1 1/2" hole in it but the size I need is the more common 2 1/8" hole. The kit I bought isn't working, the bit jumps all over and scratches the door and accomplishes nothing other than breaking the kit which is plastic. They work for one or two new holes if you are lucky, but do not work for making larger holes.

How can I enlarge the bore in my door?

Comment: If you have a question about how to do it, https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-do-i-drill-a-2%e2%85%9b-inch-door-knob-hole-over-an-existing-1%c2%bd-inch-hole may be useful. If you want to rant, this isn't the place for it.

Comment: See this Q/A: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74252/enlarging-a-deadbolt-door-knob-hole-on-a-steel-door/

Answer (score 1):

If the kit has a drill bit sticking out the end of the hole saw, ( Most kits are junk) so you may be better buying a new hole saw with a replacement type drill bit. Take the bit out of the saw and replace it with a longer (same diameter) bit. Take a piece of wood and clamp it to the other side of the door. drill a hole (same size as the longer bit ) into and thru the wood piece in the exact center.. Now you have a guide for using the larger hole saw to cut the hole larger.

Comment: A variation: use a hole saw kit to cut a plug the size of the existing hole (or several that you stack for thickness).  If it ends up a slightly smaller diameter than the hole, wrap it with tape until it fits snugly into the old hole.  Then use its pilot hole as a guide for the drill bit of the correct size hole saw.